# How to make filter regex not ignore minus sign in a line of text?

Tags: python, regex, filter

I have this text line:

`3650466536850 1.364502 1 4.330733 3.295837 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 0 3.583519 0 1 0 0 0 1 11 0 1 1.098612 0.000000 0.000000 -1`

When I changed into an array, the `-1` turn into just `1`.

```
['3650466536850', '1.364502', '1', '4.330733', '3.295837', '0.000000',
 '0.000000', '0.000000', '0', '0', '3.583519', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1',
 '1', '0', '1', '1.098612', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1']
```

Using this method:

```
for line in LinesOfFile:
    indexN = filter(None, re.split("[ \-!?:]+", line))
```

Is there something I should add to the regex to make sure the -1 is interpreted as it is?

Comment: Why are you using it as a split value when you are expecting it to be part of the value? Perhaps you shouldn't use it in the split?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you mean I shouldn't use split to turn the text into an array?

Comment: I mean you should remove `-` from the character class you are using to split with.

Comment: @Observer no he means don't use it as a delimiter in which to perform the split

Comment: Oh it's not a delimiter guys, it's a class to define the value of the line. I have a few lines and each line's value is determined either by +1 or -1! The +1 comes out fine using this split method, but only the minus gets skipped.

Comment: `"[ \-!?:]+"` -> `"[ !?:]+"`

Comment: @ReutSharabani it still skips the minus sign and give back 1 without it. While the +1 is fine.

Comment: I would be concerned with the first 4 in 4:4.330733, what consumed it?

Comment: my bad! @lossleader that is not there when I pasted in it was copied as well.

Comment: what happens to `20:1`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i removed it, it's extra text when I pasted my data, same as the 4

Comment: so what do you actually only want to split on ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the idea outcome is in the answer that I chose, which is split on `space` and `:`, while I still wanted the symbol `+` and `-` to be parsed into index as well when I turn the text line into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
for line in LinesOfFile:
    indexN = filter(None, re.split("[ \!?:]+", line))
```

I removed the `-` from `re.split("[ \-!?:]+"`, because the regex was splitting on the `-` symbol, meaning it is not included in the array.

Now if you do the following:

```
print(list(indexN))
```

You will get:

```
['3650466536850', '1.364502', '1', '4.330733', '3.295837', '0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000',      
'0', '0', '3.583519', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '11', '0', '20', '1', '1.098612', '0.000000',
 '0.000000', '-1']
```

Isn't this what you want?

Comment: THANK YOU so much! That nailed it! I needed to use the regex so badly because I'm actually tweaking an algorithm and this fixes it :)! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using a regex, can't you just do this:

```
for line in LinesOfFile:
    indexN = filter(None, re.split(" ", line))
```

It's unclear what extra mileage you're getting out of using `filter()` however.

Comment: the OP seems to be splitting on more than just whitespace

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, yes that is the reason behind using Regex.

Answer (score 0):

> you looking for something like this

```
temp=[]
    x='3650466536850 1.364502 1 4:4.330733 3.295837 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0 0 3.583519 0 1 0 0 0 1 11 0 20:1 1.098612 0.000000 0.000000 -1'
    for i in x.split():
        temp.append(i)

for x in temp:
    print x
```

Comment: Thanks Asif, I like your way of doing it, but I have way much more in my application, so it would be the best to find a regex to adopt what I have before I move on to a new solution.

Comment: why would you not just `temp = x.split()`? The op's regex also splits on `":"`